# Diagonalizing a matrix with 4 circulant blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, circulant-matrices

I have the following matrix:

$$\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix}
G_{1}^{(N)} & G_{2}^{(N)} \\
G_{2}^{(N)} & G_{3}^{(N)}
\end{pmatrix}$$,

where $G^{(N)}_{j}$ are symmetric circulant matrices of size $N-\text{by}-N$ with complex-valued entries.
Can this be diagonalized (not block-diagonalized!)?

Comment: Are the blocks (with complex entries) symmetric but not Hermitian?

Comment: hello @hardmath! Yes, exactly, it is a complex-symmetric problem! Both $G_{j}^{(N)}$, and the whole matrix $M$ are complex-symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full diagonalization, but we can end up with a block-diagonalization where each block has size only $2 \times 2$.

Let $F$ denote the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) of size $N$. Denote
$$
P_1 = I_2 \otimes F = \pmatrix{F & 0\\0 & F}.
$$
Here, $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Note that $P$ is unitary, which is to say that $P^{-1} = P^*$ (the conjugate-transpose of $P$). We find that
$$
P_1^{-1}MP_1 = \pmatrix{F^{-1}G_1^{(N)}F & F^{-1}G_2^{(N)}F\\ F^{-1}G_2^{(N)}F & F^{-1}G_3^{(N)}F} = \pmatrix{D_1 & D_2\\D_2 & D_3},
$$
and each of the matrices $D_1,D_2,D_3$ is diagonal. Now, let $P_2$ denote the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $P_2 = K^{(2,N)}$. $P_2$ is a symmetric permutation matrix, so that $P^{-1} = P^T$. We have
$$
P_2^{-1}(P_1^{-1}MP_1)P_2 = \pmatrix{A_1\\ & \ddots \\ && A_N}.
$$
Each matrix $A_j$ has size $2 \times 2$. If $D_{jk}$ denotes the $k$th diagonal entry of $D_j$, then we have
$$
A_k = \pmatrix{D_{1k} & D_{2k}\\ D_{2k} & D_{3k}}.
$$
$M$ is diagonalizable if and only if this last matrix $P_2^{-1}P_1^{-1}MP_1P_2$ is diagonalizable, which holds if and only if each matrix $A_k$ is diagonalizable. We can see that the matrices $A_k$ are symmetric with complex entries, but this does not guarantee that they are diagonalizable.

Comment: Dear Ben Grossmann, thank you for such a rapid response! I need some time to check this!

"We can see that the matrices Ak are symmetric with complex entries, but this does not guarantee that they are diagonalizable." The matrix $M$ comes from some physically meaningful problem, and I do not expect any degeneracies there, so I believe they have to be diagonalizable. 
But I have an additional question: what If I had more of such blocks, not just 2x2 matrix with 4 blocks? Could group theory help somehow in this case?

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3 I don't see any way to incorporate group theory. If you have $4$ blocks, then applying essentially the same method I suggest here should give you a block-diagonalization where the $A_k$ are instead of size $4 \times 4$.

Comment: thank you a lot! However, there is one minor additional detail. The lower left block is actually the transpose of the upper right one. It results in a fact that after block-diagonalization, the diagonal of a lower left submatrix is a permutation of the diagonal of an upper right submatrix. Now it would be nice to do somehow permute the diagonal elements of one or the other.

Comment: @Sl0wp0k3 I don't know of any way to permute the diagonal of one block without permuting every block in the same way. I think you might be stuck there. At the very least, you still end up with a block-diagonalization, but the blocks are no longer symmetric